# why have i this error on update my access data base?

Tags: c#, oledb

this is my code :

```
oledbcm = new OleDbCommandBuilder(oleDbDataAdabter);

DataRow dataRow = myDataset.Tables["salam"].NewRow();

dataRow[1] = textBox2.Text;
dataRow[2] = textBox3.Text;
dataRow[3] = textBox4.Text;
dataRow[4] = textBox5.Text;

myDataset.Tables["salam"].Rows.Add(dataRow);

oleDbDataAdabter.Update(myDataset , "salam");
```

and when i'm running it , it make this error :

> InvalidOperationException was unhandled;
>
> The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

Comment: this error happened in update line !??!?!?

Comment: can you post the exception details?

Comment: Did you specify your connection string in your `OleDbCommandBuilder`?

Comment: no!
@DaveZych: how can i do that !?

Comment: @HamedNorouzi: MSDN is your friend! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommandbuilder.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Answer (score 1):

If that's all you have than you have forgotten to create and open `OleDbConnection`. See [OleDbConnection documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.aspx) for details and examples on how to use it.

In short, you have to use it the following way:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(conectionString)) {
    //Your code here.
}
```

For this to work you need a valid connection string. It depends on what provider you use, so, refer to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.connectionstring) to determine the valid connection string format for your data source.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a `OleDbConnection` with your connection string.

```
string connectionString = 
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;"
    + "User Id=admin;Password=password;";
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM MyTable", connection);
    OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);

    connection.Open();

    DataRow dataRow = myDataset.Tables["salam"].NewRow();

    dataRow[1] = textBox2.Text;
    dataRow[2] = textBox3.Text;
    dataRow[3] = textBox4.Text;
    dataRow[4] = textBox5.Text;

    myDataset.Tables["salam"].Rows.Add(dataRow);

    oleDbDataAdabter.Update(myDataset , "salam");
}
```

Comment: i'm so sorry for the delay. i changed my code.
but it makes a new error .
this is the error : OleDbException was unhandled . Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
what should i do ?!